# Unknown class FBLoginView in Interface

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have added Facebook sdk in the bundle, and have added one view in xib whose class I have set as a 'FBLoginView' and has created outlet for the same as 'fbLoginView'. Now when I set delegate of that fbLoginView it throws an error **Unknown class FBLoginView in Interface**  and **[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa553380**

I suspect that its not getting the FBLoginView class, i have set the oultlet properly although, can somebody please help me where could I be mistaken ?

Comment: who is going to import that class?

Comment: Added the class already..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i Know  you are beginner but you have to read [Developer.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBLoginView/) there is very nice explanation. as well as they give you example code also check and match with your. you did very minor mistake for place a code.

in to your .h side:-

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate>
{
    FBLoginView *loginview;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<FBGraphUser> loggedInUser;
```

if you are trying fatch user profile pic might be you are forget to set this line of code in to app delegate:-

`[FBProfilePictureView class];`  or `[FBLoginView class];` in to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: thanks a lot buddy.. I just forgot that one line of code to put in [FBLoginView class]; in to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 7):

I had FacebookSDKResources.bundle added but still I got the error "Unknown class FBLoginView in interface builder" appearing in the xcode output pane.

To fix this I added the following line to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` :

```
[FBLoginView class];
```

This is explained in https://developers.facebook.com/ios/login-ui-control/

Comment: this is exactly the perfect thing.. thanks a lot QC :)